# Zero error, but no PDF

Tags: pdftex, linux, libertine

I just installed texlive2012 on the new distribution Mageia 3, as well as the libertine font .rpm packages. I have a problem with this code :

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{libertine}

\begin{document}
This is my first LaTeX document on Mageia 3.
\end{document}
```

when I compile I get zero error, but no PDF is built. And if I remove the libertine font, LaTeX has a normal behaviour.

I added `\listfile` and here is the corresponding `.log`

```
   article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
inputenc.sty    2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file
    utf8.def    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   t1enc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
  ot1enc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
  omsenc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
libertine.sty    2011/06/06 - 5.1.2: Font libertine - (License GPL) Michael Nie
dermair
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
lettrine.sty    2007/08/08 v1.62 (Daniel Flipo)
lettrine.cfg
    calc.sty    2007/08/22 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
     fxl.inc
     fxb.inc
     fxk.inc
     fxi.inc
   t1fxl.fd    2011/06/06 scaled font definitions for libertine T1/fxl (Nm).
 ***********
```

At the end of the `.log` I also see

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file fxlr-xl-8x): Font fxlr-xl-8x at 600 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

For kpfonts, that were installed via rpm package texlive-fontsextra, I get the same problem

```
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file jkpmn8r): Font jkpmn8r at 600 not found
==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: Could you post the full log on [pastebin](http://www.pastebin.com)?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/MfGg4Zhf

Comment: `!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file fxlr-xl-8x): Font fxlr-xl-8x at 600 not found`. It looks like pdfLaTeX can't find the font. Are you sure you installed the LaTeX font package, not the one for your Linux distribution? And have you run `texhash`?

Comment: Well, I installed only the font for the linux distro, but I can see the font is present in the texmf tree.

Comment: You should have quite a long list of files, including `fxlr-xl-8x.tfm` and `fxlr-xl-8x.htf`. If you do have those two, maybe you just need to run `texhash` to make sure pdfLaTeX can find them. If not or if still doesn't work, try (re)installing the libertine font package through the TeX Live manager.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with kpfonts, and I am sure the fonts are installed there /usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kpfonts, it comes from a package called texlive-fontsextra.

Comment: You need to run updmap-sys (as root) and if necessary add --enable Map=libertine.map. This should have been done by the distribution rpm.

Comment: I just did it, no change.

Comment: Ho, I did it other times and it… work. Thx !
The strange thing is that, I had to use the same command to be able to use kpfonts. Do I need to do it everytime for every new stuff ? Can you explain me what it is all about ?

Comment: Font packages typically contain a map file that will produce the necessary entries in psfonts.map (for dvips) and pdftex.map (for pdflatex).  But it's necessary to execute updmap-sys to produce those entries.  This should be done as a post-install step by the rpm or whatever package. You may want to complain to the packager or the bugzilla for your distribution. Or avoid the problems by installing texlive itself and uninstalling the distribution texlive packages.

Comment: @user22108 Could you make your comments into an answer?

Comment: @user22108 BTW, any chance you might pick a more memorable name :-)

Comment: @user22108 Sorry for nagging, but would you like to write an answer?

Comment: @user22108 Please, can you write an answer?

Answer (score 2):

<sub>CW answer from comments</sub>

Font packages typically contain a map file that will produce the necessary entries in `psfonts.map` (for `dvips`) and `pdftex.map` (for `pdflatex`). But it's necessary to execute `updmap-sys` to produce those entries. This should be done as a post-install step by the `rpm` or whatever package. You may want to complain to the packager or the bugzilla for your distribution. Or avoid the problems by installing TeX Live itself and uninstalling the distribution TeX Live packages.